# Which expression is equivalent to $\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x}\right) \div \frac{x-3}{x}$? (from Khan academy)

Tags: fractions

I've been trying to understand this problem for hours but not getting it. HELP!!!

The correct answer is $\frac{2}{3}$, but I don't know why this is the correct answer.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: To confirm, is the problem $$\left(\frac23 - \frac2x\right) \div \frac{x - 3}{x}?$$ Your formatting doesn't make this clear. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions clearly.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, that's the problem. Will use MathJax going forward, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my viewes,
$$\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x}\right) \div \frac{x-3}{x}$$
$$=\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x}\right) \times \frac{x}{x-3}$$
$$=2\left(\frac{x-3}{3x}\right) \times \frac{x}{x-3}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

We start with
$$\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x}\right) \div \frac{x-3}{x}.$$
As usual, we evaluate what's in the brackets first. Particularly, if we can change this into a fraction, then we'll be dividing fractions, which we can do without too much trouble. So, we wish to simplify
$$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x}$$
into a single fraction. Note the different denominator. We'll need a common denominator. Since $3$ and $x$ may not share any common factors, we'll just use their product, $3x$. We multiply the $\frac{2}{3}$ top and bottom by $x$, and the $\frac{2}{x}$ top and bottom by $3$. This gives us
$$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x} = \frac{2x}{3x} - \frac{6}{3x}.$$
Now that the denominators are the same, we subtract as usual: subtract the numerators, and keep the common denominator, so
$$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x} = \frac{2x - 6}{3x}.$$
This gives us
$$\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x}\right) \div \frac{x-3}{x} = \frac{2x - 6}{3x} \div \frac{x-3}{x}.$$
To divide fractions, we invert and multiply. Thus,
$$\frac{2x - 6}{3x} \div \frac{x-3}{x} = \frac{2x - 6}{3x} \times \frac{x}{x-3}.$$
Multiplying is as simple as multiplying numerators and denominators:
$$= \frac{(2x - 6)x}{3x(x - 3)}.$$
Finally, we can perform some factoring and cancelling. In particular, $2x - 6$ has a common factor of $2$, and is equal to $2(x - 3)$. So,
$$= \frac{2(x - 3)x}{3x(x - 3)}.$$
Finally, cancelling common factors of $x$ and $x - 3$, we get
$$= \frac{2}{3}.$$
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, Theo! Perfectly understand now.